# How do I place 3 images side by side with text to the right of each image? (Medley)

Tags: html, css

this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: this is what I am trying to achieve]

I am trying to align 3 images with text to the right of each but just can't seem to get it working in Medley. In addition, I have to code any css inline.

**Snippet**

```css
.img-valign {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
.text2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <span class="text2"><a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</strong></u></a><br><span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
  <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <span class="text2"><a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</strong></u></a>
     <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <span class="text2"><a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</strong></u></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use ```display: inline-block;``` for each of the elements. You'll need to set widths for the ```span``` elements as well.

Comment: Also, your html tags aren't closed in the correct order

Comment: You have a HTML nightmare over there. Please stop doing programming in notepad or word.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*I have to code any css inline*"

Comment: You should use `figure`and `figcaption` elements for this.

Comment: Believe me, I know the html is a nightmare! Working on an old Medley CMS system, which doesn't allow html 5, plus I do not have access to the main style sheet so I am essentially css'ing blind (in-line) and trying to clean up what I can. Medley has a lovely habit of adding all kinds of code within my code once I save to preview. It's all jacked up! Thanks to all who submitted replies. Huge help!! I'll try each one and see who the winner is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fix your HTML Issues (you closed `<strong>` before `<u>`)
2. Wrap each column inside a `div` (that div will contain the image and the content)
3. Make the image and content as floated blocks with 50% width (you can have different percentages, edit to your liking).

The final result would look something like this:

```css
.triple > div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.img-valign, .text2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-valign {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triple">
  <div>
    <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <span class="text2">
      <a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</u></strong></a>
      <br>
      <span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <span class="text2">
      <a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</u></strong></a>
      <br>
      <span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <span class="text2">
      <a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</u></strong></a>
      <br>
      <span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/3hghcscb/

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is a mess, I cleaned up, removed unnecessary tags, and use `display:flex`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  display: flex;
}
article {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1
}
.img-valign {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 5px
}
div {
  width: 50%
}
a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <div><a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a><span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <div><a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a><span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img class="img-valign" src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <div><a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a><span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. inline blocks

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

a, div, img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.card {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 32%;
}
.card a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.card div {
  width: 68%;
}
.card img {
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <div><a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a>
  <br>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <div><a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a>
  <br>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <div><a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a>
  <br>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
```

### 2. float blocks + responsive layout

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.card a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.card img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.card:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a>
  <div>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
  
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a>
  <div>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
    
<div class="card">
  <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
  <a href="cnn.com">Restaurant 100</a>
  <div>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your HTML, wrap both your images and content in the same SPAN parent.
Float left your images and use `flex`

```css
html, body{margin:0;}

.flex{
  display: flex;
}
.flex > span{
  flex: 1;
}
.flex img{
  float:left;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  <span>
    <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</u></strong></a><br>
    <span>This is some text this is some text this is some text. This is some text.</span>
  </span>

  <span>
    <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</u></strong></a>
  </span>

  <span>
    <img src="http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2016/05/18/0d/5b/image.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="cnn.com"><strong><u>Restaurant 100</u></strong></a>
  </span>

</div>
```